# Same function, different behaviour in times

Tags: javascript, recursion, out-of-memory, callstack

Here is a recursive function for endless loop.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function repeat(x){
document.write(x+" ");
repeat(x+1);
}

repeat(1);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the function, I can see how many recursive calls took place there before out of memory.
First time, I run it on firefox.

> Result -> 1 2 3 .... upto 40536

Now, I refresh the page

> Result -> 1 2 3 ... upto 46046

!! Again refreshing or running on different browsers, I got different results.

How can this be possible? What is the call stack logic/limit for recursion in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Internet Explorer 7: 1,789
Firefox 3: 3,000
Chrome 1: 21,837
Opera 9.62: 10,000
Safari 3.2: 500
```

This are all the some of limits

refer this 
http://javascriptrules.com/2009/06/30/limitation-on-call-stacks/

and also this

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/19/javascript-stack-overflow-error/

Comment: Those were very useful links. Thank you @Backtrack

Comment: Welcome @Nizam , really it was helpful for me too

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript specification does not mandate any particular memory limit.  Each implementation can impose whatever memory limit it wants.

Comment: I can`t agree with this. Because when I run the above page in IE, it shows 'out of memory'.

Comment: @Nizam IE showing "out of memory" does not in any way disprove my answer.  The JS spec doesn't impose any memory limit; the IE runtime does.  This is consistent with my answer.

Comment: I see.. So it depends on Browsers. Thanks for your time.